# How to keep alive NSTimer with NSRunLoop in background state of iOS application?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

I was using the following code to keep alive NSTimer with NSRunLoop in background state of iOS application,

```
- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:40 target:self selector:@selector(fetchMessage:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];
}
```

Using above code with xcode while debugging application in background state the NSTimer stays alive and executes the particular method on scheduled time interval. This NSTimer even works after application satys in background beyond 3 minutes of iOS 7 background execution time limit.

But I was not able to keep this NSTimer alive when application deployed on device from xcode and started using the application on device by quiting the xcode. I event tried case like restarting the application on device and send it to background by tapping on home button, but the NSTimer not executes in release mode. In debug mode of xcode it is alive in background state of application forever.

I dont want to submit application on apple app store, I want to use this functionality on my own iPhone device. Is there any way to increase the background execution time limit.

Please help me out, how to keep alive NSTimer with NSRunLoop in background state of iOS application after deployed from xcode in release mode?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` adds the timer implicitly to the runloop. Delete  both `NSRunLoop` lines.

Comment: You can use silent audio background mode if you aren't submitting to the App Store

Comment: @ Paulw11 Please give me more details about how can i use silent audio background mode for the background code execution more than 3 minutes.